# What is the analogous of the time ordering operator for theories in Euclidean space?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Correlation functions for field theories in Minkowski spacetime are refined as the VEV of the time ordered product of fields in the Heisenberg picture. Now, what happens for field theories in Euclidean space? My question is, what is the analogous of time ordering in Euclidean space?

Comment: Operators commute in Euclidean correlation functions. Operator ordering enters  upon “slicing” the Euclidean correlation function and continuing to Lorentzian time to obtain a Lorentzian expectation value. You might find [this lecture note](http://www.hartmanhep.net/topics2015/4-pathintegrals.pdf) helpful.